# Why does Amazon SES accept my get requests, but deny my similarly structured post requests?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, post, python-requests, amazon-ses

This is the code for the get request I currently use to send an email through Amazon's Simple email service:

```
import datetime
import hashlib
import hmac
import urllib.parse
import requests


def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()


def getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate = sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'), dateStamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
    return kSigning


method = 'GET'
service = 'ses'
host = 'email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
region = 'us-east-1'
endpoint = 'https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/'
access_key = 'my_access_key'
secret_key = 'my_secret_key'
my_email = 'my_email_address'

t = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
amz_date = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
datestamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d')
canonical_uri = '/'
canonical_headers = 'host:' + host + '\n'
signed_headers = 'host'
algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
credential_scope = datestamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request'

canonical_querystring_part1 = 'Action=SendEmail' \
                              '&Destination.ToAddresses.member.1={}' \
                              '&Message.Body.Html.Charset=UTF-8' \
                              '&Message.Body.Html.Data={}' \
                              '&Message.Body.Text.Charset=UTF-8' \
                              '&Message.Body.Text.Data={}' \
                              '&Message.Subject.Charset=UTF-8' \
                              '&Message.Subject.Data={}' \
                              '&Source={}'.format(urllib.parse.quote(my_email, safe=''), 
                                                  urllib.parse.quote('<b>Html Hello.</b>', safe=''), 
                                                  urllib.parse.quote('Non Html hello.', safe=''),
                                                  urllib.parse.quote('Asyncio Subject line.', safe=''), 
                                                  urllib.parse.quote(my_email, safe=''))
canonical_querystring_part2 = '&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
canonical_querystring_part2 += '&X-Amz-Credential=' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(access_key + '/' + credential_scope)
canonical_querystring_part2 += '&X-Amz-Date=' + amz_date
canonical_querystring_part2 += '&X-Amz-Expires=30'
canonical_querystring_part2 += '&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers
canonical_querystring = canonical_querystring_part1 + canonical_querystring_part2

payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(''.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash
string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' + amz_date + '\n' + credential_scope + '\n' + hashlib.sha256(canonical_request.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, datestamp, region, service)
signature = hmac.new(signing_key, string_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Signature=' + signature
request_url = endpoint + "?" + canonical_querystring


r = requests.get(request_url)
```

It is a bit long, but it runs fine. This is my attempt at doing the exact same thing, but with a post request:

```
import datetime
import hashlib
import hmac
import requests


def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()


def getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate = sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'), dateStamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
    return kSigning


method = 'POST'
service = 'ses'
host = 'email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
region = 'us-east-1'
endpoint = 'https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/'
access_key = 'my_access_key'
secret_key = 'my_secret_key'
my_email = 'my_email_address'


content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'


# Request parameters for CreateTable--passed in a JSON block.
request_parameters = '{'
request_parameters += "'body': {'Action': 'SendEmail', 'Destination.ToAddresses.member.1': '%s', 'Message.Body.Html.Charset': 'UTF-8', " \
                      "'Message.Body.Html.Data': 'HTMLMESSAGE', 'Message.Body.Text.Charset': 'UTF-8', 'Message.Body.Text.Data': 'nonHTMLmessage', 'Message.Subject.Charset': 'UTF-8', " \
                      "'Message.Subject.Data': 'subject','Source': '%s'}, " % (my_email, my_email)
request_parameters += "'Content-Type': '%s', " % content_type
request_parameters += "'context': {'client_region': 'us-east-1'}"
request_parameters += '}'


t = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
amz_date = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
date_stamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d')


canonical_uri = '/'
canonical_querystring = ''
canonical_headers = 'content-type:' + content_type + '\n' + 'host:' + host + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + amz_date + '\n'
signed_headers = 'content-type;host;x-amz-date'

payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(request_parameters.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash
algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
credential_scope = date_stamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request'

string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' + amz_date + '\n' + credential_scope + '\n' + hashlib.sha256(canonical_request.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, date_stamp, region, service)
signature = hmac.new(signing_key, string_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

authorization_header = algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + access_key + '/' + credential_scope + ', ' + 'SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature
headers = {'Content-Type': content_type, 'X-Amz-Date': amz_date, 'Authorization': authorization_header}


r = requests.post(endpoint, params=request_parameters, headers=headers)
```

Im following Amazon's documentation as best I can for the v4 signing process here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html

Im also using complete get and post request examples they have for SES found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/query-interface-examples.html

For some reason it is not working. I tried changing the kwarg in my post request from params to json to data.

```
r = requests.post(endpoint, params=request_parameters, headers=headers)
<IncompleteSignatureException>
  <Message>When Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded, URL cannot include query-string parameters (after '?'): '/?%7B'body':%20%7B'Action':%20'SendEmail',%20'Destination.ToAddresses.member.1':%20'ArbiBushka717@gmail.com',%20'Message.Body.Html.Charset':%20'UTF-8',%20'Message.Body.Html.Data':%20'HTMLMESSAGE',%20'Message.Body.Text.Charset':%20'UTF-8',%20'Message.Body.Text.Data':%20'nonHTMLmessage',%20'Message.Subject.Charset':%20'UTF-8',%20'Message.Subject.Data':%20'subject','Source':%20'ArbiBushka717@gmail.com'%7D,%20'Content-Type':%20'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;%20charset=utf-8',%20'context':%20%7B'client_region':%20'us-east-1'%7D%7D'</Message>
</IncompleteSignatureException>

r = requests.post(endpoint, data=request_parameters, headers=headers)
<AccessDeniedException/>


r = requests.post(endpoint, json=request_parameters, headers=headers)
<InvalidSignatureException>
  <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
</InvalidSignatureException>
```

Each form of post request gives a different error. Does anyone with experience in structuring post requests (or requests to Amazon's API) know what I am doing wrong?

Before anyone writes, "Use their Python SDK." I can't. Their SDK is blocking and I have to do this asynchronously. I plan to move from requests to aiohttp. I am trying to get this in requests for now because that is simpler to ask this question in.

Please help if you can, thank you for reading.

Comment: It will be very helpful if you can post the actual request bodies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wait nvm I got to. To specify a body in requests you use the "data" kwarg.

Also my variable `request_parameters` needed to be in the format `param1=This&param2=that`

Wow what a headache.